# How to round off decimals in values when ISNULL exists in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I have problem with rounding off decimals in this pivot table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUjxQ.png)

Here's the code:

```
SELECT P.LastName,  [Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0), [Bottles and Cages]=ISNULL([Bottles and Cages],0), [Bottom Brackets]=ISNULL([Bottom Brackets],0), [Brakes]=ISNULL([Brakes],0)
FROM #TabPivot 
PIVOT (
SUM(Total)
FOR Name IN ( [Bike Racks], [Bottles and Cages], [Bottom Brackets], [Brakes])) AS P
ORDER BY P.LastName;
```

I tried to use ROUND and CAST...AS NUMERIC functions but it didn't worked (maybe I did something wrong):

```
SELECT P.LastName,  ROUND([Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0),2), ...

SELECT P.LastName,  ROUND(([Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0)),2), ...

SELECT P.LastName,  ROUND(([Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0), [Bottles and Cages]=ISNULL([Bottles and Cages],0), [Bottom Brackets]=ISNULL([Bottom Brackets],0), [Brakes]=ISNULL([Brakes],0)),2)

SELECT P.LastName,  CAST([Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0) AS Numeric(15,2))

SELECT P.LastName,  CAST([Bike Racks]=ISNULL([Bike Racks],0)) AS Numeric(15,2)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Sample data (as DDL and DML statements) and expected results (not as an image) will help us help you. It's unclear what you're asking here

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide a single [mre] which we can copy and paste out. Rather than a bunch of different queries and some results in an image, and no desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column name cannot be inside the function, but outside, try this:

```
SELECT [Bike Racks] = cast(isnull(0.66666, 0)  as decimal(18,2))
```

as an alternative, maybe it's more clear when you use the AS syntax for specifying column name:

```
SELECT cast(isnull(0.66666, 0)  as decimal(18,2)) AS [Bike Racks]
```

Comment: It didn't made an error (query executed) , but it didn't round off values

Comment: sorry you're right, it should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to cast your data to a *decimal* data type specifying the correct *scale* and *precision*.

For example

```
declare @v float=14
select @v/3.066, Cast(@v/3.066 as decimal (5,2))
```

Returns

```
4.5662100456621 4.57
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Select Convert(Decimal (17,0),[Bike Racks]) AS [Bike Racks with convert]
      ,Floor(ISNULL([Bike Racks], 0)) AS [Bike Racks round down number]
      ,Ceiling(ISNULL([Bike Racks], 0)) AS [Bike Racks round to up number]
```

you can find other model of round and usable in below example :

```
DECLARE @value decimal(10,2)
SET @value = 11.05

SELECT ROUND(@value, 1)  -- 11.10
SELECT ROUND(@value, -1) -- 10.00 

SELECT ROUND(@value, 2)  -- 11.05 
SELECT ROUND(@value, -2) -- 0.00 

SELECT ROUND(@value, 3)  -- 11.05
SELECT ROUND(@value, -3) -- 0.00

SELECT CEILING(@value)   -- 12 
SELECT FLOOR(@value)     -- 11
```

[Reference](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/)